Pandoc filter to treat (Python) script output as Markdown
I need a Pandoc filter that takes Python as the code block, runs it, and then treats the output of the script as Markdown. Something like:
# Heading

```{.pyscript}
import datetime.datetime
print(f"The current date and time are {str(datetime.now()}.")
```

and then running pandoc like this:
$ pandoc --filter pyscript file.md -o file.html

(presuming that "pyscript" is the name of the filter) to turn the above into this:
# Heading

The current date and time are 2024-12-17 14:11:28.684357

which pandoc will then format appropriately (as HTML in this particular case). Does any such pandoc filter exist?

yes,It does exist.
from datetime import datetime
def greet4():
    return f"The current date and time are {str(datetime.now())}."

If function returns a value instead of print and display.Checkout the link https://_12.pyscriptapps.com/user-inputs-copy-copy/latest/

I'm not seeing how that answers the question, which pertains to Pandoc.

Not sure if pyscript works the way you are trying.You can directly upload main.py file instead of doing this way?

Python as code block I figured out not sure of the Pandoc.
def greet4():
    html_content = f"""
     <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2023.03.1/pyscript.css" />
   <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2023.03.1/pyscript.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <py-script>
       from pyscript import display
       display("hello")
    </py-script>
</body>
</html>
    """
    return html_content

